# Response 504 for calling database on shortenning url

Tags: node.js

I´m not getting response from db gets 504 error

https://glitch.com/~well-frigate

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);
```

Comment: please include relevant code in the question

Comment: it´s in the link above

Comment: @AndréMartins there is no link above, only what seems a code constant that contains an URL. Please try to elaborate on the problem at hand. For example: which server are you trying to connect to? From where are you trying to connect to it? Does other methods of connection work? (E.g. from a database desktop client.)

Comment: I´m trying to connect to the mongo db atlas cluster collection from a glitch project yes, locally with mongo and docker it works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for editing my own question difficulting to get help.
Finally it works. For someone who interest the project is in the link of question

What I did to work it was update mongoose version!